# Can't connect Appium Inspector and emulator

Tags: appium, appium-android

I have added JAVA_HOME, ANDROID_HOME and other environment variables but still, it complains.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The picture doesn't show that you've set those variables. It just shows you're using those in another variable, maybe PATH?

Answer (score 0):

Before starting the appium server, click on the `Edit Configurations` and setup the `Android_Home` and `JAVA_HOME`